# Download Scala and Spark API docs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Seth's comment below listing a URL in the maven repo, seems to be both correct, and general. Following the logic, I also found the spark docs at:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.10/2.2.1/spark-core_2.10-2.2.1-javadoc.jar

Which means that in effect my question is answered, but since Seth didn't give an "answer" I can't mark it as such. Not sure what to do about that!

----------------- original question below -----------------

I fear I'm being unobservant or obtuse, but I have been unable to find where I can download the API docs for Scala, and also for Spark. I know where they are online, and I suppose I might try a recursive "wget", but I'm leery of that since I'm not sure I could get it to produce anything that works locally anyway. Perhaps I need to build them locally, but that too seems like a lot of effort since I can't quite believe these resource don't exist in a ready-made form.

In case this seems like a stupid request, I spend half my life on the road, on aeroplanes with expensive, low quality, (and theoretically unnecessary!) internet connections, or in the middle of nowhere, so I'm in the habit of installing all my tools and resources, particularly including API docs locally. That was easy with Java, but not so obvious with these two technologies.

Can anyone tell me where to find a downloadable package for each, or if I do in fact have to use one of the techniques I mentioned in my opening paragraph?

Comment: Scala: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.12.4/scala-library-2.12.4-javadoc.jar . if you're on MacOS, consider using https://kapeli.com/dash for all your offline documentation needs

Comment: You could write an answer and credit Seth.

Comment: Can I credit him in the SO "points" sense? My question gives the spiritual kudos now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seth, who made the first comment under my original question nailed this. I'm adding this essentially so that the question shows as answered.

In summary:
Both documentation sets are downloadable from the maven repositories:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.12.4/scala-library-2.12.4-javadoc.jar

and

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.10/2.2.1/spark-core_2.10-2.2.1-javadoc.jar

It appears that this is a general observation that's likely applicable to many if not most packages that maven has to offer.